# Fix floating point imprecision in ceiling

Tags: r, floating-point, floating-point-precision, ceil

The problem:

```
ceiling(31)
#31
ceiling(31/60*60)
#32
```

What is the correct way to fix this kind of errors?

Doing the multiplication before the division is not an option, my code looks something like this:

```
x <- 31/60
...
y <- ceiling(x*60)
```

I'm thinking of doing a new function:

```
ceil <- function(x) {
  ceiling(signif(x))
}
```

But I'm new to R, maybe there is a better way.

**UPDATE**
Sorry, I didn't give more details, I have the same problem in different parts of my code for different reasons, but always with ceiling.

I am aware of the rounding error in floating-point calculation. Maybe the title of the question could be improved, **I don't want to fix an imprecision of the ceiling function**, what I want to do is perhaps the opposite, make ceiling less exact. A way to tell R to ignore the digits that are clearly noise:

```
options(digits=17)
31/60*60
#31.000000000000004
```

But, apparently, the epsilon required to ignore the noise digits depends on the context of the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: ceiling is exact, so there is no imprecision in it to fix. `/` and `*` on the other hand are not exact for all inputs, and since this is an intrinsic property of these floating-point operations, the fix is not to use them.

Comment: I don't see why this was downvoted. OP is not asking why this happens, but how to deal with it. A vvery reasonable question, well posed.

Comment: This seems to work (similar to your own solution): `ceiling(signif(31/60*60,-log10(.Machine$double.eps)))`.

Comment: Would either round() or ceiling(x-0.4) be beneficial?

Comment: @PascalCuoq I don't want to fix an imprecision of the ceiling function, see the update for more details. Feel free to change the title for a better one if that is what is giving the wrong idea.

Comment: @jlhoward that looks more robust than my solution, would you care to explain how it works in an answer?

Comment: note that `options(digits=...)` affects *output* precision, not floating-point imprecision in the calculations.

Comment: @BenBolker I know, I put it so I could be able to show the noise in the result

Answer (score 1):

The real problem here, I strongly believe, is found in my hero The Data Munger Guru's tagline, which is:  "What is the problem that you are trying to solve? 
Tell me what you want to do, not how you want to do it. "

There are myriad cases where floating-point precision will cause apparent integers to turn into "integer +/- epsilon" , and so you need to figure out why you are going for "ceiling" , why you allow your values to not be integers, etc.   <-- more or less what Pascal Cuoq wrote in his comment.

The solution to your concern thus depends on what's actually going on.  Perhaps you want, say `trunc(x/60)->y` followed with `trunc(y*60)` , or maybe not :-) .  Maybe you want `y<-round(x/60*60) +1` , or jhoward's suggested approach.   It depends, as I stress here, critically on what your goal is and how you want to deal with corner cases.

Comment: I want ceiling. I want ceiling(30.9) == 31, ceiling(31) == 31, ceiling(31.1) == 32.

Comment: you're missing the point of my answer:  sure you want "ceiling" , but why and for what purpose?